# Scraping instagram post date

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, instagram

I was trying to scrape instagram to get the recent post dates. I was using selenium to get the work done. But when I use get_element_by_xpath and give the path of date text it says element not found . I have tried using scrolling the page but it didn't work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

new='https://www.instagram.com/p/Bf1Xl9Pgvvy/?tagged=meditation'

##finding poster user link and date 
browser.get(new)

element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/div[2]/a/time')))
```

Comment: You should give a bit more information about your problem if you want to get some help.

Comment: You are basically asking someone to do this for you. If that is the case, then go hire a developer. If that is not a case, then first you need to try to do it yourself. If that fails, then come back and ask your question. Along with a full example. If you do not show any code, you will more than likely not get any help.

Comment: I have tried all methods. If I use requests module it doesnt get the whole code due to javascript limitations. If I use selenium it says element not found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use as simple XPath as possible for your task.
This will work for you:

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//time')))
```